# STdeconvolve Top 1000 Overdispersed Genes Error

Tags: r, spatial

I am working with some spatial transcriptomic data (10x genomics visium) using the STdeconvolve R package. I am able to see the package through, however, I do get an error when attempting to narrow down corpus to the top 1000 "overdispersed" genes (aka those that show the highest variance between spatial positions) that I would like to solve before extracting final results as I am unsure if this will affect the final output. I have attempted this with both tissue positions data "cleaned" to remove any empty spots that had no tissue and therefore no transcriptomic data, as well as with the raw data including the empty spots that should have been removed by the cleanCounts script line below.

Code up until error:

```
remotes::install_github('JEFworks-Lab/STdeconvolve')

## read in and set up data
pos.info<- read.csv('~/Documents/Visium/Zhang_Carolyn__NoHS1_A1/outs/spatial/tissue_positions.csv')
head(pos.info)
pos <- pos.info[, c('pxl_row_in_fullres', 'pxl_col_in_fullres')]
head (pos)
rownames(pos) <- pos.info$barcode
head(pos)
plot(pos)
library(Matrix)
gexp <- Matrix::readMM('~/Documents/Visium/Zhang_Carolyn__NoHS1_A1/outs/filtered_feature_bc_matrix/matrix.mtx.gz')
dim(gexp)
gexp[1:5,1:5]
barcodes <- read.csv('~/Documents/Visium/Zhang_Carolyn__NoHS1_A1/outs/filtered_feature_bc_matrix/barcodes.tsv.gz', sep="\t", header=FALSE)
head(barcodes)
dim(barcodes)
colnames(gexp) <- barcodes$V1
features <- read.csv('~/Documents/Visium/Zhang_Carolyn__NoHS1_A1/outs/filtered_feature_bc_matrix/features.tsv.gz',sep="\t", header=FALSE)
head(features)
dim(features)
dim(gexp)
rownames(gexp) <- features$V2
gexp[1:5,1:5]

## quality check
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
hist(log10(colSums(gexp)+1))
hist(log10(rowSums(gexp)+1))
plot(pos)

## library per read spot
library(ggplot2)
head(pos)
df <- data.frame(pos, libsize=colSums(gexp)[rownames(pos)])
ggplot(df, aes(x=pxl_col_in_fullres, y=pxl_row_in_fullres, col=libsize)) + geom_point()

library(STdeconvolve)

## remove pixels with too few genes
counts <- cleanCounts(counts = gexp,
                      min.lib.size = 100,
                      min.reads = 1,
                      min.detected = 1,
                      verbose = TRUE)

## feature select for genes
corpus <- restrictCorpus(counts,
                         removeAbove = 0.95,
                         removeBelow = 0.05,
                         alpha = 0.01,
                         plot = TRUE,
                         verbose = TRUE)
```

**Error Message:**

```
> corpus <- restrictCorpus(counts,
+                          removeAbove = 0.95,
+                          removeBelow = 0.05,
+                          alpha = 0.01,
+                          plot = TRUE,
+                          verbose = TRUE)
Removing 68 genes present in 95% or more of pixels...
17995 genes remaining...
Removing 5220 genes present in 5% or less of pixels...
12775 genes remaining...
Restricting to overdispersed genes with alpha = 0.01...
Calculating variance fit ...
Using gam with k=5...
3551 overdispersed genes ... 
 Using top 1000 overdispersed genes.

Error in intI(i, n = x@Dim[1], dn[[1]], give.dn = FALSE) : 
  invalid character indexing
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In asMethod(object) :
  sparse->dense coercion: allocating vector of size 1.2 GiB
2: In asMethod(object) :
  sparse->dense coercion: allocating vector of size 1.2 GiB
```

I am more so concerned with the "Error in intI(i, n = x@Dim[1], dn[[1]], give.dn = FALSE) :
invalid character indexing" rather than the additional warning messages.

Thank you in advance for any input/suggestions!